# Raise Custom Exception if Value is Less than Indicated Value

Tags: ruby, exception

I am writing a code where the user has to input an integer, and the code needs to raise custom exceptions with a custom text in two cases:
a) if the input is not an integer
b) if the integer is smaller than 8

I did the first part:

```
begin
  print "Enter the price: " 
  price = Integer gets
rescue
  puts "Error: the entered value is not a number"
  raise
end
```

But I have no idea how to raise an error if the entered number is less than 8. It needs to look like this:

```
Enter the price:
==> 7

Output:
==> Error: the minimum price needs to be at least 8 euro
```

Sorry for such a basic question. I'm still learning and exception handling are pretty fresh topic for me.

Comment: Right now, you print the text and raise an exception without text. To have a custom exception with custom text you probably want something like `raise "the entered value is not a number"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can raise an exception like this:

```
if price < 8
 raise ArgumentError, 'the minimum price needs to be at least 8 euro'
end
```

Comment: That works! Thanks! Ideally, however, I would like to skip 'ArgumentError' completely or change it simply to "Error" or other custom name to not confuse the user?

Comment: I just used `ArgumentError` because that is the matching default exception built into Ruby (see: [Ruby's Exception vs StandardError](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-exception-vs-standarderror-whats-the-difference/)). But feel free to use something else when it fits your domain better.